# Why does gcc complain about my loops?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, for-loop

I have some fairly trivial code, still gcc complains (in `-O3 -march=native`) about loop unrolling:

```
cannot optimize loop, the loop counter may overflow [-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations]
for(auto& plan : fw)
^
```

Here is a (stripped of all fftw stuff, else it would be quite long) version of my code

```
class FFTWManager
{
    public:
        void setChannels(unsigned int n)
        {
            fw.resize(n);
            bw.resize(n);
                            //some fftw-specific stuff comes here
        }

        void forward()
        {
            for(auto& plan : fw)
                fftw_execute(plan);
        }

        void backward()
        {
            for(auto& plan : bw)
                fftw_execute(plan);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<fftw_plan> fw = {};
        std::vector<fftw_plan> bw = {};
};
```

The vectors never exceed a size of 2 in my code.

---

Edits according to comments : 
I use a lot of flags.

`-pedantic -Wextra -Weffc++  -Wall -Wcast-align  -Wcast-qual  -Wchar-subscripts  -Wcomment -Wconversion  -Wdisabled-optimization    -Wformat  -Wformat=1  -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security   -Wformat-y2k  -Wimport  -Winit-self  -Winline  -Winvalid-pch    -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations  -Wmissing-braces  -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-format-attribute    -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn  -Wpacked  -Wparentheses  -Wpointer-arith  -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type  -Wsequence-point  -Wshadow -Wsign-compare  -Wstack-protector -Wstrict-aliasing=3 -Wswitch  -Wswitch-default  -Wswitch-enum -Wtrigraphs  -Wuninitialized  -Wunknown-pragmas  -Wunreachable-code -Wunused  -Wunused-function  -Wunused-label  -Wunused-parameter  -Wunused-value  -Wunused-variable  -Wvariadic-macros  -Wvolatile-register-var  -Wwrite-strings`

I don't see the point of speaking of putting infos about `fftw_execute` here but if you want to see the whole code (that I judged too long for a SO post), it's here :
https://github.com/jcelerier/watermarking/blob/master/src/libwatermark/transform/FFTWManager.h

GCC : `gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-10)`

I don't see why changing from unsigned int to size_type would change anything since I don't get any warning in my `setChannels` method (even if I think it's long unsigned int on my platform) and once the size is set, the original type of the variable that was used to set it seems quite irrelevant to me.

There is no warning with the basic `for(int i = 0; i < bw.size(); i++)` or with the iterator version `for(auto i = bw.begin(); i != bw.end(); i++)`.

I also tried with clang, which seems to recognize the warning swich so I guess they also implemented the optimization, and I don't get any warnings (but much quicker compile times \o)

Sorry about long feedback, I was out.

Comment: Ignore it. Not every warning ought to make sense.

Comment: What if you change `unsigned int` to `std::vector<fftw_plan>::size_type`?

Comment: While the size won't exceed 2 in your code, the compiler does not know that when looking locally at the function. The warning is just telling you that the optimizer is not doing loop unrolling for that particular loop. You might want to try to rewrite the loop in terms of the size or iterators and see if the optimizer is happier with that.

Comment: fftw_execute is missing (-1)

Comment: Warnings are almost always relevant and should be eliminated, not ignored.

Comment: Silly compiler complaining about its own generated code (its implementation of a C++11 range based `for` loop). Not much to do about that except, if possible, telling it to shut up. General observation: g++ is, IME, quite a bit weird in the optimization department.

Comment: Countering the -1 with a +1 because the implementation for `fftw_execute` is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: you might try an ordinary `for` loop instead, with signed loop counter so that g++ can rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: Sounds merely like he hit the -Wall.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? Can you please show *all* flags you use for compiling? It might actually be a bug in GCC, it's not common to hit those but they do exist.

Comment: I have tried your class with header and main() function, with command `g++-4.7 -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -march=native test.cpp -lfftw3`. But no error show up, how exactly are you compile it?

Comment: The trouble is in 'fftw_execute' passing a reference to the function.

Comment: meh am i blind or stupid g++ is not realizing that he is looping over a vector?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl make fftw_execute an inline function operating on some 'plan' which is an FFTWManager, too

Comment: Without any OP feedback, it is impossible to resolve it (hence my -1 sticks)

Comment: edited the question with feedback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From gcc manual:

> `-funsafe-loop-optimizations`
>
> This option tells the loop optimizer to assume that loop indices do not overflow, and that loops with nontrivial exit condition are not infinite. This enables a wider range of loop optimizations even if the loop optimizer itself cannot prove that these assumptions are valid. If you use `-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations`, the compiler warns you if it finds this kind of loop.

Thus, apparently, the implementation of range-for loop in the compiler is somehow broken in that it triggers this warning. You could either disable this particular warning or disable this particular optimization... I would advise the latter as it is unclear to me whether the optimization is actually done or not when the warning is triggered.

Comment: The error message says `cannot optimize loop` so I hope that no optimization is done here... It would be quite weird.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier: I hope so, too.

Comment: I'm trying to make a minimal contained example that reproduces this behavior right now...